# SQL with rank and partition

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I need to execute this sql:

```
select * from 
(select nt.*, 
        rank() over (partition by feld0 order by feld1 desc) as ranking
 from (select bla from test) nt)
where ranking < 3 
order by 1,2
```

This sql works fine in my oracle database but in the h2 database which i use sometimes this doesnt work because rank and partition are not defined.

So i need to transform this sql so that it works in h2 and oracle.

I want to use java to execute this sql. So is it possible to split this sql into different sqls without rank and partition? And then to handle it with java?

Comment: H2 does not support windowing functions, you cannot translate that query to H2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `feld1` is unique within `feld0` partitions, you could:

```
select  *
,       (
        select  count(*)
        from    YourTable yt2
        where   yt2.feld0 = yt1.feld0 -- Same partition
                and yt2.feld1 <= yt1.feld1 -- Lower or equal rank
        ) as ranking
from    YourTable yt1
```

Comment: funny, that works! but what about for more than one `order by` ?