# H2 database - Alternative to Rank() and Row_Num()

Tags: sql, h2

I am using H2 database in my java application. It seems that it doesn't support `rank()` and `row_num()` functions as they are still on their [roadmap list](http://www.h2database.com/html/roadmap.html)

Here's the query that I am trying to execute

```
select * from (
   select *,
          rank() over(partition by MSISDN order by PORT_IN_DATE desc) rank 
   from TEST_PORTIN
) s 
where rank = 1 
  AND PORT_IN_DATE > '2012-01-16 23:20:27' 
ORDER BY PORT_IN_DATE
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL with rank and partition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8861457/sql-with-rank-and-partition)

Comment: See also the H2 forum: http://groups.google.com/group/h2-database/browse_thread/thread/f063de014c88bda7

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `RANK()` for your particular query. You can rewrite it as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM TEST_PORTIN t1
WHERE PORT_IN_DATE > '2012-01-16 23:20:27'
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM TEST_PORTIN t2
    WHERE t1.MSISDN = t2.MSISDN -- PARTITION BY clause translation
    AND t1.PORT_IN_DATE > t2.PORT_IN_DATE -- ORDER BY clause translation
)
ORDER BY PORT_IN_DATE
```

Or, a bit fancier (but not necessarily faster), using a quantified comparison predicate

```
SELECT *
FROM TEST_PORTIN t1
WHERE PORT_IN_DATE > '2012-01-16 23:20:27'
AND PORT_IN_DATE >= ALL (
    SELECT PORT_IN_DATE
    FROM TEST_PORTIN t2
    WHERE t1.MSISDN = t2.MSISDN
)
ORDER BY PORT_IN_DATE
```