# Is it possible that left side in a left outer join to repeat only once

Tags: mysql, sql-server, optimization, h2, outer-join

I have a scenario. Not sure if it is at all possible by simple sql query.

**Table1**

```
create table table1 (rowno int,
                     fileid int,
                     filename varchar(50),
                     filedata varchar(50),
                     valid boolean
                     );

insert into table1 (RowNo , FileId , FileName , fileData , Valid) values
(1, 1, 'FileA', 'blah blah..', true),
(2, 1, 'FileA', 'blah blah..', true),
(3, 1, 'FileA', 'blah blah..', true),
(4, 1, 'FileA', 'blah blah..', true),
(1, 2, 'FileB', 'blah blah..', false),
(2, 2, 'FileB', 'blah blah..', true),
(3, 2, 'FileB', 'blah blah..', false);
```

Above will give a table as follows, -

```
RowNo | FileId | FileName | Data        | Valid
1     |1       | FileA    | blah blah.. | TRUE 
2     |1       | FileA    | blah blah.. | TRUE 
3     |1       | FileA    | blah blah.. | TRUE 
4     |1       | FileA    | blah blah.. | TRUE 
1     |2       | FileB    | blah blah.. | FALSE 
2     |2       | FileB    | blah blah.. | TRUE 
3     |2       | FileB    | blah blah.. | FALSE
```

**Table2**

```
create table table2 (fileid int,
                     rowno int,
                     errormsg varchar(100)
                    );
insert into table2 (fileid , rowno , errormsg ) values (2,1,'manatory field is blank');
insert into table2 (fileid , rowno , errormsg ) values (2,3,'date format is wrong');
```

Above will give a table as follows, -

```
FILEID  |ROWNO   |ERRORMSG   
2       |1       |manatory field is blank 
2       |3       |date format is wrong
```

If I join the above table with the below query, -

```
select distinct t1.FILENAME,tot.TOTALREC, VALIDREC,coalesce((tot.TOTALREC- VALIDREC),0)INVALIDREC, t2.Rowno , case when coalesce((tot.TOTALREC- VALIDREC),0)=0 then null else t1.filedata end as ErrorData , t2.errormsg as ErrorMessage
from table1 t1
join (select count(*) totalrec, fileid from table1 group by fileid)tot on t1.fileid=tot.fileid
join (select count(*) VALIDREC , fileid from table1 where valid=true group by fileid)valid on t1.fileid=valid.fileid
left outer join table2 t2 on t1.fileid=t2.fileid 
order by t1.FILENAME;
```

I get the following result, -

**Actual Result**

```
FILENAME | TOTALREC | VALIDREC | INVALIDREC | ROWNO | ERRORDATA | ERRORMESSAGE   
FileA    |   4      |    4     |     0      | null  | null      | null 
FileB    |   3      |    1     |     2      | 1     |blah blah..| manatory field is blank 
FileB    |   3      |    1     |     2      | 3     |blah blah..| date format is wrong
```

But I need a result set as below.

**Expected Result**

```
FILENAME |TOTALREC|VALIDREC|INVALIDREC|ROWNO| ERRORDATA | ERRORMESSAGE   
FileA    |   4    |    4   |    0     | null| null      | null 
FileB    |   3    |    1   |    2     | 1   |blah blah..| manatory field is blank 
         |        |        |          | 3   |blah blah..| date format is wrong
```

(Notice the first four columns in last row.)

If this is possible, can anyone help me with the query?

**Updated:** *To clarify my requirement as many of you have requested so.*

Comment: I am sure that whatever it is you are trying to do is possible. However, as posted it is extremely unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Can you briefly explain why the expected result is like that only?

Comment: It's possible in SQL Server.   Don't know about MySQL.

Comment: Which are you looking for: MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: @halfer--> The database can be anything. In my case it was H2 database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all thank you all for all your help.

**@Rick** --> This is possible.

I was looking for the solution for some time now particular to H2 database. But nevertheless, the solution should hold good for most of the databases that support **ranking** or anything that achieves that. I found the **ranking** approach in this [Stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8861457/sql-with-rank-and-partition).

After that it was piece of cake!!

Here is the solution query for those who are interested, -

```
select 
case when (final.INVALIDREC>0 and final.ranking>1) then '' else final.FileName end as FileName,
case when (final.INVALIDREC>0 and final.ranking>1) then '' else cast(final.TOTALREC as varchar(50)) end as TOTALREC,
case when (final.INVALIDREC>0 and final.ranking>1) then '' else cast(final.VALIDREC as varchar(50)) end as VALIDREC,
case when (final.INVALIDREC>0 and final.ranking>1) then '' else cast(final.INVALIDREC as varchar(50)) end as INVALIDREC, final.Rowno , final.ErrorData , final.ErrorMessage
from
(select 
   (
    select  count(*)
    from    (select distinct t1.FILENAME, t2.Rowno from table1 t1
    left outer join table2 t2 on t1.fileid=t2.fileid 
    order by t1.FILENAME) yt2
    where   yt2.FILENAME = temp.FILENAME -- Same partition
            and yt2.Rowno <= temp.Rowno -- Lower or equal rank
    ) as ranking,
temp.FILENAME,temp.TOTALREC, temp.VALIDREC,temp.INVALIDREC, temp.Rowno , temp.ErrorData , temp.ErrorMessage
from
(select distinct t1.FILENAME,tot.TOTALREC, VALIDREC,coalesce((tot.TOTALREC- VALIDREC),0)INVALIDREC, t2.Rowno , case when coalesce((tot.TOTALREC- VALIDREC),0)=0 then null else t1.filedata end as ErrorData , t2.errormsg as ErrorMessage
from table1 t1
join (select count(*) totalrec, fileid from table1 group by fileid)tot on t1.fileid=tot.fileid
join (select count(*) VALIDREC , fileid from table1 where valid=true group by fileid)valid on t1.fileid=valid.fileid
left outer join table2 t2 on t1.fileid=t2.fileid 
order by t1.FILENAME, t2.rowno) temp)final;
```

This will give the **Expected Result**.

*Thanks all.. this is my first post in Stack Overflow and am feeling humble in getting so much help..

Happy coding!!*

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you want certain fields to be left blank if they are the same as the corresponding fields in the previous row?

There is no way to do that directly in MySQL.  You would be better off doing it in an application language (PHP, VB, Java, etc).

You *could* do it with use of @variables, `IF()` function calls and `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 0):

Can't see what SQL you've used there but as a general rule if you have something like:

```
CASE WHEN RANK() OVER (PARTITIION BY a.filename ORDER BY a.rowno DESC) = 1 THEN <insert column here> END
```

It'll filter out duplicates dependant on which is the first row in each file etc.

In SQL Server this does provide a means of applying masks to some records and not others.

Comment: It's unclear which database the OP has, but afaik MySQL does not have windowing functions.

Comment: @Simon--> Right. That is what I did over there. The database in my case was H2 Database. And it took me a while to find out the rank thing in H2.

Answer (score 0):

COALESCE is what you want.

```
Select t.myfield, coalesce(t2.Myfield2, '') 
from mytable t
left join mytable2 t2 on t.mytableid = t2.mytableid
```